# place small footnotes on the same line

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

The informal version of the style guidelines for my college papers (a condensation of Turabian's style) states that small footnotes may be placed on the same line with a minimum of six spaces separating. Is there a way to do this with the footnoting capabilities of Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem so, at least for Word 2007 (and previous versions). Footnote formatting options are limited to formatting of the numbers or symbols used, and of course to font and paragraph formatting. I tried applying a column formatting to the footnotes, but it is disabled.

Comment: That's kinda what I was running up against. Let me wait a bit (week or so), and if nothing good happens, I'll accept this one. Thanks!